# Google cloud MX records not created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to add mx records for my domain akvastar.ru

**Screenshot**

[image: here is screenshot]

But no MX record found if I check here: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=akvastar.ru&dkim_selector=

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've set MX records for the subdomain `@.akvastar.ru` instead of the apex domain. Remove the record, and add a new record without a subdomain.